# Product links to multiple stores

Tags: buttons, layout

The product in this case is an Album, and I am trying to decide from a few different layouts/interactions.

The challenge comes from providing the options allowing user preference : itunes, amazon, google play, cdbaby.

1. Display just one Buy button, with different store options in a popover.
2. Display a grid of buying options for each store.

My feeling is that one Call To Action is better than multiple buttons.

Comment: A mockup would really help here

Comment: Will this be displayed in product page ? What are the factors that distinguishes each store ? Can you provide little more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Although one button (option 1) makes your interface cleaner. I prefer the multiple buttons (option 2) for these reasons:

1) User can tell at a glance what are the stores available.
2) Returning user don't have to perform 2 clicks to purchase a product. Assuming that their store preference doesn't change much.

As what other commenters said, more context on where the button is located and used would help us come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I believe music buyers are usually divided in terms of what services they are loyal to. There is some overlap, but most already know-prefer one of these services, Itunes, Google play, Amazon, Spotify etc. I think giving them options right away for most popular choices is better. Than having one obscure button with no idea what it does or where it takes the user to after its clicked..

I would do something like this or a version of this depending on your choice..

[image]

Where as if I have this approach below, as a user I am not sure what the buy button does. Its kind of uncertain to me at this stage.. its also one extra step most users dont really need to go through ..

[image]

Comment: +1 exactly what I was about to put. options up front with retailer names gives the benefit of saying - this album is available to buy from these providers. this information is invaluable and shouldn't be hidden in a popover.

Comment: a bare minimum would be to provide a list of places it is available from (if buttons are too big), then the links could then be hidden in a popover accessible from one button.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't comment yet, so have to use the Answer option. Are you just after opinions or do you have a more specific question?

If you're asking us to choose between options 1 and 2, then I agree - one call to action is a better approach, especially if you're going to have five potential options. So option 2 it is for me.